# Points in Polygon Query but having CRS issues (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have two files:

1. A csv file that has lat longs listed for points.
2. A shapefile that contains England NHS CCG boundaries (which usually uses the British National Grid).

When I 'add a delimited layer', if I opt to geocode the lat/long data to BNG, it doesn't like it.  But if I change the NHS CCG shapefile to a CRS of WGS84, then it looks curved.

I just want to do a query that tells me what CCG boundary each of these points reside in (so either a point in polygon query or a join attributes by table query).

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! Is the **Project CRS** set to the same CRS as your 2 layers?

Answer (score 2):

In `Settings -> Options, CRS`tab, select `Prompt for CRS` for new layers.

Then you can choose WGS84 when loading the delimited text file.

The other file should remain in BNG. Don't use `Set CRS for Layer` to change it. This will **NOT** reproject your coordinates.

Instead, use `Save As...` on the delimited text layer, choose a different filename and BNG as CRS.

The query will not work with delimited text layers, and both layers must be saved to disk with the same CRS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joseph and AndreJ for responding.

Just in case anyone reads this and is interested, I found another work around.
I loaded the delimited layer (which had the lat longs), saved it with a CRS of British National Grid. Then reopened this layer and created a query where I created 2 new fields, one with the x coordinate and the other the y coordinate (in the expression field use: $x)

Then with both of my layers now being BNG, I was able to the spatial query